How to import csv file in MySQL to avoid the appearance incorrect symbols
I imported a CSV file into MySQL. Before that, I checked the encoding of the file and confirmed it was UTF-8. When I imported the file, I ensured that my database was set to the utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci encoding, but it still contains strange symbols in my columns.


I tried to change charset of my existing database in different encoding but it still has the same result.
And I noticed when I fixed the charset to ascii then I got an error like this:
Error 1366: Incorrect string value: '\xD0\x93\xC2\xB1a' for column 'Last name' at row 2 SQL Statement: ALTER TABLE `clientvalidata`.`data`  CHANGE COLUMN `Last name` `Last name` VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET 'ascii' NULL DEFAULT NULL

How can I archive the correct render of my characters? Thanks

Could we have details on how you import the file?

I imported CSV into MySQL using Workbench and I can provide simple guide that helped me on that: https://blog.n8n.io/import-csv-into-mysql/ - the first approach

Check ALL charset settings (client, server, connection, ..).

For now I can only check my database, I haven't bounded it with UI or server. I added a screenshot where I did it. Where else can I check it?

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'

by using this command I got 8 rows:
All of them have "utf8mb4", but only "character_set_filesystem" has "binary", "character_set_system" has "utf8mb3" and "character_sets_dir"  has  - 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets'
How can use it in order to fix this issue? Thanks

I resolved the issue by the following steps:
I created again new schema and marked the following charsets:

utf8mb4 & utf8mb4_es_0900_ai_ci
After doing this, I didn't automatically create a new table using the Workbrench UI 
I created it using MySQL code, explicitly specifying the encoding for each column:
CREATE TABLE clientdata (
First_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_es_0900_ai_ci,
Last_name VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_es_0900_ai_ci....
 

Then i also imported csv file by using MySQL code:
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Cliente_911 - BBDD (1).csv'

INTO TABLE clientdata
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(First_name,
Last_name...
